# Create new record for Join Table from a form.select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First steps with RoR, trying to wrap my head around basic concepts. Following excercise: I have pupils and schoolclasses, both Active Record entities with a many to many (has_and_belongs_to_many) to each other. Now I have a form to create a new pupil. On this form there is also a form.select to pick the class for the pupil, but I can´t get this to work, I can´t get the controller to create a new record for the join table.

Schoolclass.rb

```
class Schoolclass < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pupils
end
```

Pupil.rb

```
class Pupil < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :schoolclasses
end
```

Relevant part of the _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :schoolclass %>
  <%= form.select(schoolclass.id, schoolclasses_for_select) %>
</div>
```

schoolclasses_for_select is just a helper for populating the select box

```
def schoolclasses_for_select
  Schoolclass.all.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.schoolyear] }
end
```

Everything I have tried on the controller has failed miserably. Somehow, I mostly end up  with the controller trying to pass the schoolclass (as a String) as an attribute to the new Pupil, or with a MethodNotFound error. In my understanding it should work something like this :

```
@klass = params[:schoolclass]
pupil.schoolclasses << @klass
```

but it doesn´t.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit1: the create code

```
def create        
  @pupil = Pupil.new(pupil_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @pupil.save       
    format.html { redirect_to @pupil, notice: 'Pupil was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pupil }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @pupil.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
def pupil_params
  params.require(:pupil).permit(:nachname, :vorname, :schoolclass)
end
```

That is the part that works. What I haven't managed is to find the correct Schoolclass record and pass it to the pupil.

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: Can you show the create action code?

Comment: Depending on which misguided idea i try, I see a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues

- First argument to your `form.select` should be the field name i.e. `:schoolclass_id`. You can still keep the label `Schoolclass`.
- I believe you want `id` of schoolclass to be passed in params when selected. For that to happen, change your options for select to `Schoolclass.all.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id] }`
- **Biggest**, Your association says a pupil can have multiple schoolclasses but your form doesn't support it. Have you handled it some other way?

#### Fixes

So, do something like (this does **not** support multiple schoolclasses selection):

```
<%= form.select :schoolclass_id, Schoolclass.all.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id] } %>
```

And in your controller

```
def create        
  @pupil = Pupil.new(pupil_params)

  # Find schoolclass from `schoolclass_id` and associate it to `@pupil`
  schoolclass = Schoolclass.find(params[:pupil][:schoolclass_id])  # Handle case when schoolclass not selected in form
  @pupil.schoolclasses |= [schoolclass]

  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end

private

def pupil_params
  params.require(:pupil).permit(:nachname, :vorname)
end
```

Comment: I am going to handle the multiple classes issue elsewhere on the frontend. These are literally my first lines typed in RoR and your answer cleared a couple of issues for me , thanks. I still find the "magic" of Rails  handling naming, getters, setters and all sorts of things  in the background, rather confusing.

Comment: Yeah, it may be a bit confusing in the beginning. You will get used to the _magic_ as you try your hands on it. :)